# How to Export a selection of Keyframe Animation

Tags: animation, export, gltf

I want to export a Keyframe Selection as glb file. I import mocap data, clean it up and want to export a part of the animation as glb for a webprojekt. But there ist no chance to get only a selection of this.

The Animation is about 20000 Keyframes, I want only Keyframe 450 to 800 for the export. I try it with the start and endkeyframe for rendering, but blender will export all 20000 Keyframes.

Thanks for Any help.

Answer (score 1):

Save a new version of the file, open a dopesheet window, turn it into an action editor, select the mesh or the armature which has the animation you want to export, delete all unwanted keyframes, move the keyframes all togheter so to set their start at frame 1 and export.